# "Not today anymore"?

Tags: sentence-choice

If someone asks whether I want to play and I plan not play for the rest of the day could I answer : "No, not today anymore." or would it have to be different? "No more today" or perhaps "I dont want to play anymore today." What would be a good answer?

Comment: Are you trying to be polite, informal or rude?

Comment: I didnt even think about that, I guess Id pick polite or informal then but not rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standar answer which would cover all polite, informal, and formal would be the patterns

> I had enough *ing* for today.
>   I *(simple past)* enough for today.
>
> I had enough *playing* for today.
>   I *played* enough for today.

meaning you are finished with whatever activity it was for the rest of the day.

It also works for other things

> I had enough *beer* for today.
>   I had enough *sun* for today.
>
> I *drank* enough for today.
>   I *sunned* enough for today.